Menu text items are not appearing
I just recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my computer and whenever I go to any menu everything appears to be greyed out until I move my cursor over the items. I've already installed Gnome Tweaks and ensured everything was set to system default and I am still getting the same error.


You say in the question 24.04 but the tag is 22.04 please correct.


Are you using NVidia graphics card? If so, open Additional Drivers and switch to a different driver. 2. If not, try creating a new user and


Thanks, I switched to a different driver and eventually it worked.

I had the same issue even after updating the NVidia drivers. Just update the /etc/environment file with this line:
GSK_RENDERER=gl

After that logout or restart your system. This fixed my issue.

Thanks, I switched to a different driver but I also updated this just in case.
